# Cant sync from google calendar to my .Net Mvc Web App

Tags: c#, api, push-notification, google-calendar-api

I am trying to do sync from google calendar to my .NET MVC Web App.

I created a callback method that `Googles Calendar API` will send the new event in calendar to. But I don't get the new google calendar event instead I am getting this `error`:

> 2021-07-09 12:52:26,982 [              37] DEBUG DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging                                                         - The following required parameters were missing from the DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2.Messages.AccessTokenFailedResponse message: {error,
> }
>
> 2021-07-09 12:52:26,997 [              37] WARN
> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging
> Multiple message types seemed to fit the incoming data: {AccessTokenSuccessResponse (2.0), UnauthorizedResponse (2.0), }
>
> 2021-07-09 12:52:27,013 [              37] DEBUG
> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
> Received AccessTokenSuccessResponse response.
>
> 2021-07-09 12:52:27,013 [              37] INFO
> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
> Processing incoming AccessTokenSuccessResponse (2.0) message:    access_token:
> <Access_Token_Number>
> token_type: Bearer  expires_in: 3599    scope:
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar
>
> 2021-07-09 12:52:27,013 [              37] DEBUG
> DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.Channel
> After binding element processing, the received AccessTokenSuccessResponse (2.0) message is:   access_token:
> <Access_Token_Number>
> token_type: Bearer  expires_in: 3599    scope:
> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar

**How can I handle this ?**

**EDIT (adding code)**

```
 public void PushNotificationCallback()
    {
        try
        {                
            var header = Request.Headers;
         
            NotificationResponse notification = new NotificationResponse(header["X-Goog-Channel-Expiration"], header["X-Goog-Channel-Id"], header["X-Goog-Message-Number"], header["X-Goog-Resource-Id"], header["X-Goog-Resource-State"], header["X-Goog-Channel-Token"], header["X-Goog-Resource-Uri"]);   
       
           therapistCalendarEntryController.PushNotificationCallback (notification);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
          ...
        }            
    }
```

**And in the controller action**

```
public void PushNotificationCallback(NotificationResponse response)
    {                        
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response?.HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_TOKEN))  surrounded with if
        {
            var TherpistRepisitoryCallback = TherapistRepository ?? (Global.IoC.TryResolve<IRepository<Therapist>>());
            var therapistId = new Guid(response.HTTP_X_GOOG_CHANNEL_TOKEN);
            var therapistCall = TherpistRepisitoryCallback.Get(therapistId);                

            if (therapistCall != null)
            {
                SyncGoogleCalendarEvents(therapistCall, null, true);
            } 
        }         
    }


public void SyncGoogleCalendarEvents(Therapist therapist, string pagingToken, bool syncAllEvents)
    {            
        var TherpistRepisitoryCallback = TherapistRepository ?? (Global.IoC.TryResolve<IRepository<Therapist>>());
        var TherapistCalendarEntryRepositoryCallback = TherapistCalendarEntryRepository ?? (Global.IoC.TryResolve<IRepository<TherapistCalendarEntry>>());

        try
        {
            Encoding encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            string SyncTokenStr = "";
            string PageTokenStr = "";

            if (pagingToken != null)
                PageTokenStr = "&pageToken=" + pagingToken;
            if (therapist.SyncTokenGoogleCalendar != null)
                SyncTokenStr = "&syncToken=" + therapist.SyncTokenGoogleCalendar;                

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(new Uri(@"https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?showDeleted=true" + PageTokenStr + SyncTokenStr, UriKind.Absolute));
            if (therapist.RefreshTokenGoogle != null)
            {
                var authenticator = GetAuthenticator(therapist);
                GoogleAuthorizationHelper.apply((GoogleApiUtils.GoogleAuthenticator)authenticator, request);
            }
            request.Method = "GET";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";

            try
            {
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                string jsonString = GetResponseJson(response);
                PrintResponseJson(jsonString, "sync from google calendar");

                var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

                if (data["nextPageToken"] != null)
                {
                    if (syncAllEvents == true)
                    {
                        AddGoogleCalendarEventToTipulog(therapist, TherapistCalendarEntryRepositoryCallback, data);
                    }

                    SyncGoogleCalendarEvents(therapist, data["nextPageToken"].ToString(), syncAllEvents);
                }
                else
                {
                    saveTherapistNextToken(therapist, TherpistRepisitoryCallback, data);
                    if (syncAllEvents == true)
                    {
                        AddGoogleCalendarEventToTipulog(therapist, TherapistCalendarEntryRepositoryCallback, data);
                    }
                }             

            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                ...
            }

            catch (Exception e)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
           ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include [example]

Comment: @DaImTo I tried to add all the relevant code

Comment: Any reason you are not using the google .net client library?  Your issue is that you haven't added a authorization header containing the access token which has been authorized with the proper scope.

Comment: @DaImTo thanks, can you please add some example code with missing `header`?

Comment: Not really as i use the Google .net client library which handles all that for me if your going to reinvent the wheel go for it.   Just look up how to add an authorization header.

Comment: @DalmTo can you give me an example using google.net with .NET MVC ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a tutorial which shows how to set up a MVC project for authorization with the Google people api [Asp .net core 3 and Google login](https://www.daimto.com/asp-net-core-3-and-google-login/)

Once you have the DI set up you can then call the the API you wish.

```
 // This configures Google.Apis.Auth.AspNetCore3 for use in this app.
 services
     .AddAuthentication(o =>
     {
         // This forces challenge results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, so there's no
         // need to add an AccountController that emits challenges for Login.
         o.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         // This forces forbid results to be handled by Google OpenID Handler, which checks if
         // extra scopes are required and does automatic incremental auth.
         o.DefaultForbidScheme = GoogleOpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
         // Default scheme that will handle everything else.
         // Once a user is authenticated, the OAuth2 token info is stored in cookies.
         o.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       })
       .AddCookie()
       .AddGoogleOpenIdConnect(options =>
       {
          options.ClientId = ClientId;
          options.ClientSecret = ClientSecret;
           });
```

There is a companion video to the blog post [How to get a Google users profile information, with C#.](https://youtu.be/aqjglbdFGPk) But its with the Google people api.

Here is an example of how to adapt it for google calendar api.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// List all calendars in a users Calendar List.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="auth"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [GoogleScopedAuthorize(CalendarService.ScopeConstants.Calendar)]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index([FromServices] IGoogleAuthProvider auth)
    {
        var cred = await auth.GetCredentialAsync();
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = cred
        });

        var response = await service.CalendarList.List().ExecuteAsync();
        return View(response);
    }
```

I am in the middle of editing a video for Google calendar